# Converting Firebase anonymous user to user with email and password - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm having trouble to convert an anonymous Firebase user to a registered user with email and password.

My code look's like this:

```dart
Future linkAnonymousAccount({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    try {
      await _auth.currentUser!.linkWithCredential(
        auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email: email, password: password),
      );
      // await refreshUser();
    } on auth.FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      throw LinkAnonymousAccountException(e.code);
    }
  }
```

It seem's like `EmailAuthProvider.credential` creates a new user (with new uuid and everything) instead of converting the current anonymous user.

So after creating an anonymous user with:

```dart
Future signInAnonymously() async {
    try {
      await _auth.signInAnonymously();
    } on auth.FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      throw SignInException(e.code);
    }
  }
```

And then calling the `linkAnonymousAccount` - method from above I get the following result in my firebase console:

[image: result in console]

But so I lose all user data like *displayName* and *photoUrl* and also all the data in my database (due to the different uuid's).

I'm not able to find a solution for this or an explanation why this is happening.

I found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JLl5M4N7ftM&t=2375s) where this is not the case and the anonymous user is actually converted. But I use the same code as the guy in the video and get a different result.

Am I missing something? Has someone an explanation for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible - there is a built-in methods for that

For example, user was logged in Anonymously and after that started Apple login.

```
  final appleProvider = AppleAuthProvider()
    ..addScope('email')
    ..addScope('fullName');

  final UserCredential user;
  if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
    user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.linkWithProvider(appleProvider);
  } else {
    user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithProvider(appleProvider);
  }
```

As a result, you will have one user, logged in with Apple, with the same id that had an Anonymous user.